# How to send notifyDataSetChanged from one activity to previous activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView in an activity. listView contains 2 buttons and one field that gets updated when button is clicked. Onclick on a listView open a new activity for same item (detail description of item).

In new activity again i have 2 buttons and one field that gets updated when button is clicked.

The problem is after updating in detailed activity if user back press button to go to previous activity, updated field value does not reflected there.

How to send notifyDataSetChanged from detailed activity to previous activity?

Is public void onResume() is the place where we can do some trick?

Answer (score 1):

Star second activity for result

```
startActivityForResult(...)
```

then catch the result in

```
onActivityResult(...)
```

From there you can call notifyDataSetChanged by comparing request & result code

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onResume()`, although I would suggest that you use `startActivityForResult()` instead. Once the user presses back you get `onActivityResult()` (with `resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED`) where you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

This latter approach has the advantage that you can pass some data from the second activity to the first (in an `Intent`), for example a boolean that tell whether to notify the adapter. Then you check this data in `onActivityResult()` and decide what to do.